# C# time driven event

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to complete my college assignment, which asks to create a time driven event. A report should be automatically emailed to a responsible person twice everyday. I need to get the times from a database which I can do quite easily. For now, I have created a timer like this:

```
private static void getDate()
  {
      DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime alarm = new DateTime(2015, 10, 27, 19, 23, 0);

      TimeSpan diff = alarm - now;

      System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
      // Set the Interval to the difference in time from now to your alarm. 
      if (diff.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
      {
          aTimer.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
          aTimer.Enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
          aTimer.Enabled = false;
          aTimer.AutoReset = true;
          aTimer.Dispose();
      }
  }
```

When the form is initialized, the getDate() function is executed to start the timer. When the timer hits the specific time, I run this code:

```
 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
      XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
      transformer.Load("report.xsl");
      transformer.Transform("Report.xml", "Report.html");

      string html = File.ReadAllText("Report.html");
      SendMail(html);
  }
```

After the e-mail is sent to a person, I run the getDate() function again to update the time. However, the timer doesn't seem to stop. It defaults to Interval of 100.00 and runs the OnTimedEvent() is executed. I am not sure what changes I should make. So basically the timer needs to run off two different times during the day. When the report is sent both times, it should default to the earliest time the following day (if that makes any sense).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: `However, the timer doesn't seem to stop.` Perhaps you should turn it off then once it's fired? `aTimer.Enabled = false`.

Comment: put a counter in OnTimedEvent and when its 2 stop the timer.

Comment: It's sad that they're teaching you to use `Timer` for a timed event when a scheduler like Windows Scheduler would be more appropriate in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

`Timer` has a property of `AutoReset`, set this to `false` to disable it automatically restarting after the `Elapsed` event.

e.g.:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer
{
    AutoReset = false
};
```

Comment: This has done the trick! Thank you very much. Whats the best way to set the timer to the correct time the next day, once the report has been sent twice already? IE, if I report is scheduled to be send at 9am and 8pm, how should I tell the system to update the timer to the next day, after the report is sent at 8pm?

      DateTime alarm = new DateTime(2015, 10, 27, 19, 39, 0);

Comment: I don't get you, do what to that line?  I've added some sample code to the answer in case that's what you were asking.

Comment: Sorry, see my edited comment. Pressed enter too soon.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's a bit more tricky.  Do you have to use the `Timer` class or can you use something else?

Comment: Well the assignment specifically states " Create Timer Driven event" so I take it that I do have to use the Timer class

Comment: OK, well then I'd be looking at creating two timers with 24 hour duration for the two daily events.  You'll need two to trigger the partial day interval for when you get the first event.  NB, Timers are disposable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93534/discussion-between-user3468334-and-banksysan).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getDate()` again it is creating a second (new) instance of Timer. Your first Timer is still ticking. To fix this, you need to move the Timer instantiation out of the getDate() method. Move it to the constructor

```
//Move this to the constructor  
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
```